# How to eliminate multiple similar sql queries with one resultset handler?

Tags: c++, database, qt, c++11, sqlite

I have some similar sql queries, all of the selected fields are same, just the condition is different. So, the resultset handlers are same also. I use sqlite3 and [sqlite_modern_cpp](https://github.com/aminroosta/sqlite_modern_cpp).

Here are two of the similar functions(there are several others):

```
QVariantMap getItemById(int id) {
  QVariantMap map;
  database db(dbfile);
  db << "select id,name,price,qty from items where id=?"
     << id 
     >> [&] (int id, std::string name, double price, int qty) {
     map.insert("id", id);
     map.insert("name", QString::fromStdString(name));   
     map.insert("price", price);
     map.insert("qty", qty);
  };
  return map;
}

QVariantMap getItemByCatAndSeq(int cat, int seq) {
  QVariantMap map;
  database db(dbfile);
  db << "select id,name,price,qty from items where cat=? and seq=?"
     << cat << seq 
     >> [&] (int id, std::string name, double price, int qty) {
     map.insert("id", id);
     map.insert("name", QString::fromStdString(name));   
     map.insert("price", price);
     map.insert("qty", qty);
  };
  return map;
}
```

You see, all of the fields in the queries are "id,name,price,qty" and the resultset handlers are same also.

One resultset handler should be enough, but I have to copy&paste the same code in each function. In addition, the names and orders of the selected fields must be matched with the parameters resultset handler -- lambda function.

How to eliminate this kind of duplicated code? Is there a better solution for this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I tried the functor way, as follows:

```
struct ItemResultHandler {
    explicit ItemResultHandler(QVariantMap& map_) : map(map_) {}
    void operator() ( int id, std::string name, double price, int qty ) {
         map.insert("id", id);
         map.insert("name", QString::fromStdString(name));   
         map.insert("price", price);
         map.insert("qty", qty);
    }
    QVariantMap& map;
};
```

One of the above two similar functons will be changed into this:

```
QVariantMap getItemById(int id) {
  QVariantMap map;
  database db(dbfile);
  db << "select id,name,price,qty from items where id=?"
     << id 
     >> ItemResultHandler(map);
  return map;
}
```

But, it has compiling errors:

```
../../myapp/src/utility/function_traits.h:12: error: type 'void (ItemResultHandler::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
        decltype(&Function::operator())
                  ^

 ../../myapp/src/sqlite_modern_cpp.h:218: error: incomplete definition of type 'sqlite::utility::function_traits<ItemResultHandler>'
                        binder<traits::arity>::run(*this, func);
                               ~~~~~~^~
```

Comment: This seems too obvious but can't you put the duplicate code in a function?

Comment: Thanks. The variable map is local, moving the duplicate code into a function means that I have to use a member variable. That's a not good way. I have tried functor, but it has compiling errors.

Comment: pass the variable map by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem with mapping all those different result types we handle. So the Template got a bit complex and it looks like it does not handle this case.

Here is an example how you could do it with the type extensions.

```
// The thing you want
struct Item {
    int id;
    string name;
    double price;
    int qty;
};
// to get it back we need to give a deserialization method:
namespace sqlite {
    template<> void get_col_from_db(database_binder& db, int inx, ::Item*& ret) {   // specify the type it will be used on, a pointer is necessary if you’re type has no default constructor. Otherwise a object ref does the job too.
        ret = new Item();
        get_col_from_db(db, inx++, ret->id);
        get_col_from_db(db, inx++, ret->name);
        get_col_from_db(db, inx++, ret->price);
        get_col_from_db(db, inx++, ret->qty);
    }
}

{// usage
    Item* item;
    db << "select val,name,price,qty from test" >> item;
    std::cout << item->name;
    delete item;
}
```

But this is ugly and definitely needs to change, i will get rid of this pointer mess in the next Version.

There is however a shorter version, just convert youre functor to a lambda in this way, substituting youre QMap with my struct:

```
auto ItemResultHandler = [](Item& item) -> std::function<void(int, std::string , double , int )> {
    return [&item](int id, std::string name, double price, int qty) mutable {
        item.id = id;
        item.name = name;
        item.price = price;
        item.qty = qty;
    };
};
```

and just use it like this:

```
Item item;
db << "select val,name,price,qty from test" >> ItemResultHandler(item);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the shorter version.